# C# Trouble with detection is point in polygon?

Tags: c#, geometry

I have polygon with these points:

> A= (-8598.07,7513.37)
>
> B= (-8598.07,5169.17)
>
> C= (-8496.47,5271.77)
>
> D= (-4735.47,5271.77)
>
> E= (-4736.47,7411.77)
>
> F= (-8497.47,7411.77)
>
> G= (-4838.07,7310.17)
>
> H= (-4838.07,5372.37)

So my polygon has 8 segments.

And I have point 'I' inside the polygon

> (-6616,6802.6537)

[image]

Using this popular algorithm:

```
public bool IsPointInPolygon(Point2D[] polygon, Point2D testPoint)
        {
               var result = false;
            var j = polygon.Count() - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < polygon.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (polygon[i].Y < testPoint.Y && polygon[j].Y >= testPoint.Y || polygon[j].Y < testPoint.Y && polygon[i].Y >= testPoint.Y)
                {
                    if (polygon[i].X + (testPoint.Y - polygon[i].Y) / (polygon[j].Y - polygon[i].Y) * (polygon[j].X - polygon[i].X) < testPoint.X)
                    {
                        result = !result;
                    }
                }
                j = i;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

But it return false.

My List with points:

```
(-8598.07; 7513.37 -> -8598.07;5169.17)
(-8496.47; 5271.77 -> -4735.47;5271.77)
(-4736.47; 7411.77 -> -8497.47;7411.77)
(-4838.07; 7310.17 -> -4838.07;5372.37)
(-8598.07; 7513.37 -> -8497.47;7411.77)
(-8496.47; 5271.77 -> -8598.07;5169.17)
(-4736.47; 7411.77 -> -4838.07;7310.17)
(-4735.47; 5271.77 -> -4838.07;5372.37)
```

The known working C code is:

```
bool pointInPolygon() {

  int   i, j=polyCorners-1 ;
  bool  oddNodes=NO      ;

  for (i=0; i<polyCorners; i++) {
    if ((polyY[i]< y && polyY[j]>=y
    ||   polyY[j]< y && polyY[i]>=y)
    &&  (polyX[i]<=x || polyX[j]<=x)) {
      oddNodes^=(polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x); }
    j=i; }

  return oddNodes; }
```

Comment: Where is "Popular algorithm" from? At first glance it looks like "Incorrect Algorithm" is a better name

Comment: @Jamiec I tested it many times, http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: So you are porting C code and it doesn't work? Can you include it into a question? Another thing - there are no A, B, C, D ... in array, so we need to check if you define it correctly, can you show input data (how method is called and with which parameters).

Comment: @Sinatr Added to question list with points

Comment: @Sinatr I think problem not in that algorithm, maybe it's in point order or maybe this algorithm doesn't work with that type of polygon(if yes it will be strange)

Comment: Umm... your points are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Rotem So if I sort them in for example clockwise order it should work?

Comment: It's not about clockwise or counterclockwise. The point order in your list does not constitute the line that is drawn in your diagram, it constitutes a self intersecting polygon. Connect the dots and see.

Comment: @Rotem So, I connected dots. But I don't get you. With these points I form that polygon. But in strange order, yeah.

Comment: Obviously the order needs to be consecutive. I don't understand the 'My List with points` section you posted. Each line has 2 points, and the 2nd point in each line doesn't match the 1st point of the following line, so what exactly does this represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order them in that way:

> (-8598.07, 7513.37, -8598.07, 5169.17)
>
> (-8598.07, 5169.17,-8496.47, 5271.77)
>
> (-8496.47, 5271.77, -4735.47, 5271.77)
>
> (-4735.47, 5271.77, -4838.07, 5372.37)
>
> (-4838.07, 5372.37, -4838.07, 7310.17)
>
> (-4838.07, 7310.17, -4736.47, 7411.77)
>
> (-4736.47, 7411.77, -8497.47, 7411.77)
>
> (-8497.47, 7411.77,-8598.07, 7513.37)

You just need to "close" the polygon.